# UIImageview propotion with stackview auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I am using `UIStackView` and Dimention of stackview is "Fill Proportionally".

[image]

In a first view of above hierarchy, I have a `UIImageView` with 1:1 aspect ratio.

[image]

But **for some reason view controller shows warning of misplaced view. Why so?** I can't understand whats wrong with my constraints.

2nd thing is if I'll accepting change frames and use other devices variations than sometime `UIImageView` height and width were not same it changes regardless its 1:1 ratio. for e.g if 70:70 width and height is than after device variations it changed to 70:71 or 69.5:10:5 .. what was happening here??

After accepting Update frames : (check the width and height of UIImageView where width != height for 1:1 ratio )

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

And one more thing is my proportion height for three views are like 135, 105 and 240 respectively but when I reopen the project, it changed to 160,160 and 151. So, is this a default behaviour?

Here is [Demo link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=64424149952594898686) if you want to test this issue.

Comment: you are not adding constraint to right control.

Comment: what do you mean by that? @AbdulRehmanWarraich ... I am adding constraint to its super view .. why it is not right control?

Comment: you need to start from to bottom in the hierarchy. First add constraint to the  stackView then inner view and then to ImageView.

Comment: ya thats what I do ... @AbdulRehmanWarraich and thats why there is warning and not an error .. if I am not giving any constraints to superviews than there should be an error not warning

Comment: let me check you code.

Comment: Do you need fix width and height of imageView ?

Comment: no ... I want image ratio ... and thats why this question is asked for :) otherwise I know it fixed this warning

Comment: select the imageView and click update frame and share screen short.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich can you check my full question where I already tell about this too and there is an issue too ..

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you not added Leading constraint.

You need to set y position of imageView.

Here is a project [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25813549078120276004)

Comment: I already have center X .. so that means it should be at center with top and bottom constraint and aspect ratio ... no need to give leading constraint here ...

Comment: @vadim there is no need of leading constraint if the horizontal center is added with width constraint.

Comment: @VadimKozak my constraint and question is not realted to fix width and height ... its about proportional imageview height and width

Answer (score 0):

I checked your project and there is no issue at all. Only select the ImageView and click "Update Frame". And set the top and bottom space equal.
Aspect ration is rounded so that it is difference of 1 or less.

The Aspect ration is calculated according to the view height and ImageView Height is always equal to **(View height - 61)**, **And Width is rounded**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: my proportion height for three views are like 135, 105 and 240 respectively but when I reopen the project, it changed to 160,160 and 151. So, is this a default behaviour? try to change the proportion heights to 135, 105 and 240 respectively and that change devices and check width and height

Comment: do you want fix height for the Views ?
-------If yes then add height constrain to all views and delete bottom constraint of stack view
-------if no then set equal height of each view to main view and change multiplier accordingly.